# How to enlarge the area of the object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

OK, I have made simple rectangular using OpenGL, and it looks pretty simple

```
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glVertex3f(-0.0, 2.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 2.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

and small as well. So my Q. is how can I make this twice as bigger using one single line of code or how can I make lets say only X axis values to be doubled. I know it's possible, but I have no idea what function to search for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends if you want to double the size of the triangle, or move the 'camera' closer to the model.  Although both options give you the same result, the methods are entirely separate methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can move the camera closer by using `glTranslate` or scale the scene using `glScale`. But frankly?

```
x *= 2.0;
y *= 2.0;

glVertex3f(-0.0, y*2.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(x*1.0, y*2.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(x*1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

... this is the way to go.

Comment: That's it! :) Thanks @Kornel Kiselowicz.

Comment: OpenGL has no camera. And translating the geometry closer to the view origin has only an effect if a perspective projection is used.

Comment: @datenwolf, I know, but it seemed easier to state it that way.